# Fermat Last Theorem for non Integer Exponents

Tags: number-theory

We now that Fermat's last theorem is true so there are not positive integer solutions to
$$x^n+y^n=z^n$$
for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $n>2$.

But what about if $n\in\mathbb{R}$ or $n\in\mathbb{R}^+$?

Comment: You may find this useful: Fermat’s Last Theorem for Fractional and Irrational Exponents, College Math. J. 41 (2010), 182-185

Comment: Also http://math.williams.edu/fermats-last-theorem-for-fractional-exponents/

Comment: Didn't Wiles et. al. solve this in the n∈R domain ?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Suppose $z> \max(x,y)$  then $x^0+y^0 = 2 > z^0$ but there exists some $N$ such that $x^N+y^N<z^N$.  Therefore there exists some $n\in[0,N]$ satisfying $x^n+y^n=z^n$.

Comment: You can generalise this to show that the set of real `n` for which there exist integers $x, y, z$ with $x^n + y^n = z^n$ is dense in $[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 18):

Take $x=4, y=9$ and $n = 0.5$. You can solve to get $z = 25$. So this works!

Comment: Could you give some insights on how did you find that solution?

Comment: Use any perfect square for x and y if n=0.5  And so you can also use any perfect cube for x and y if you pick n = 1/3, for example x = 27, y = 64, you find z = 343

Comment: Do you have an example for n rational and > 2?

Comment: No, I don't unfortunately

Comment: x=4,y=9 and z=25 is not a triangle let alone a right triangle, so in the context of FLT.this is not really an answer. It appears to be a common feature of FLT that the problem context is set either too narrow or broad. There are 2 constraints: that of: 1. the right triangle and 2. the set of x,y,h,n∈R, with 1 further constraining 2 to n∈R+. Solving beyond this is unnecessary, but possible, however you may end up with a unnecessarily complex proof as per Wiles et. al.. I have proposed a simple proof in my answer to this question below and welcome feedback.

Comment: @MarcusAnderson your proof is wrong, and the answer has been deleted. This is because FLT only seeks solutions to $x^n+y^n=z^n$ when $x,y,z\in\mathbb Z$ for $n\in\mathbb Z^+$ and $n\geq3$, and no "constraints" of the type you mention exist.

Answer (score 10):

$1782^n + 1841^n = 1922^n$ with $n \approx 11.999999995097161$

Comment: Yes. Now I realized I can solve this even with my TI-Nspire; $solve(1782^x+1841^x=1922^x,x)$.

Comment: Dan, how is this possible? I thought there were not supposed to be integer solutions with n greater than 2? Isn't that what Fermat is about? I typed it in my calculator and it comes out evenly, is my TI rounding or something?

Comment: Ah, there is rounding, never mind. 1782^12 is even, 1841^12 is odd, but 1922^12 is even. Wiles is indeed a clever man...

Comment: @imranfat: It's possible because the exponent is a non-integer.  It just happens to be really close to one.