# Integral solutions $(a,b,c)$ for $a^\pi + b^\pi = c^\pi$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

We know that $a^n + b^n = c^n$ does not have a solution if $n > 2$ and $a,b,c,n \in \mathbb{N}$, but what if $n \in \mathbb{R}$? Do we have any statement for that?

I was thinking about this but could not find any immediate counter examples.

Specifically, can $a^\pi + b^\pi = c^\pi$ for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}$?

I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394548/fermat-last-theorem-for-non-integer-exponents?rq=1). It has a existential proof that $\exists \ n \in \mathbb{R}$ for any $(a,b,c)$

The question remains open for $n = \pi$.

This question is just for fun to see if we can some up with some simple proof :)

Comment: See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+a%5Epi%2Bb%5Epi%3Dc%5Epi+over+the+integers, where Wolframalpha does not seem able to find any solutions.

Comment: @ChadShin $a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}$ and not $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: That doesn't matter. Wolframalpha does not know any non-zero integer solutions. This seems to imply there are no natural solutions.

Comment: @Chad Shin Wolfram Alpha doesn't know any non zero solutions to $a^3 + b^3 = c^3$ but that does not put us in any better position to prove Fermat's Last Theorem :)

Comment: Which is why I did not post this as an answer. It seems that it probably isn't. Your problem is very interesting.

Comment: It should be straightforward (ish) to show that the set of $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that there are $a, b, c\in\mathbb{N}$ with $a^x+b^x=c^x$ is countable, so even though it's dense in (an interval of) the reals (as per a note in the linked question) almost no real numbers actually satisfy the requirement.

Answer (score 6):

The Wikipedia article on Fermat's last theorem [has a full section about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem&oldid=708132381#Exponents_other_than_positive_integers), with plenty of references. Here are a few results (see the article for precise references):

- The equation $a^{1/m} + b^{1/m} = c^{1/m}$ has solutions $a = rs^m$, $b = rt^m$ and $c = r(s+t)^m$ with positive integers $r,s,t>0$ and $s,t$ coprime.
- When $n > 2$, the equation $a^{n/m} + b^{n/m} = c^{n/m}$ has integer solutions iff $6$ divides $m$.
- The equation $1/a + 1/b = 1/c$ has solutions $a = mn + m^2$, $b = mn + n^2$, $c = mn$ with $m,n$ positive and coprime integers.
- For $n = -2$, there are again an infinite number of solutions.
- For $n < -2$ an integer, there can be no solution, because that would imply that there are solutions for $|n|$.

I don't know if anything is known for irrational exponents.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture](Schanuel's conjecture) the answer is negative. The fact that I have to resort to Schanuel's conjecture suggests that the question is impossible to answer provably.

Schanuel's conjecture says that if the numbers $x_1, ... x_n$ are linearly independent over the rationals, the transcendence degree of $x_1, e^{x_1} ... x_n, e^{x_n}$ is at least $n$. To use Schanuel's conjecture I have to divide the argument into cases depending on which of the logarithms of $a$, $b$, and $c$ are linearly independent. Note that $c$ cannot be $1$, as $a$ and $b$ are positive integers and thus at least $1$ (if one of them is $0$, it's a trivial solution), so that $c^\pi \ge 2$ and $c \gt 1$, and also note that $a$ and $b$ cannot both be $1$ as that would imply that $c=2^{1/\pi}$, which is not an integer as $1 \lt 2^{1/\pi} \lt 2$.

Case 1: $a=1$ (meaning that $\log a=0$) and $\log b$ and $\log c$ are rational multiples of each other. This means that $r_1\log b = r_2\log c$ and $b^{r_1}=c^{r_2}$ for integers $r_1$ and $r_2$. Write $b=p^{r_2}$ (so that $\log b = r_2\log p$) and $c=p^{r_1}$ (so that $\log c = r_1\log p$). Thus the equation $a^{\pi}+b^{\pi}=c^{\pi}$ becomes $1+p^{r_2\pi}=p^{r_1\pi}$ Since $p$ is a real number greater than 1, $\log p$ is a nonzero real number, while $i\pi$ is a (nonzero) imaginary number, so $\log p$ and $i\pi$ are linearly independent. Thus Schanuel's conjecture implies that two of the numbers $x_1=\log p, e^{x_1}=p, x_2=i\pi, e^{x_2}=-1$ are algebraically independent. Since $p$ and $-1$ are algebraic, it must be $\log p$ and $i\pi$ that are algebraically independent. Thus $\pi\log p$ is linearly independent with $\log p$ and $i\pi$, so Schanuel's conjecture implies that three of the numbers $x_1=\log p, e^{x_1}=p, x_2=i\pi, e^{x_2}=-1, x_3=\pi\log p, e^{x_3}=p^{\pi}$ are algebraically independent; since $\pi\log p$ is clearly not algebraically independent with the others, this means that the three numbers $\log p$, $i\pi$ and $p^{\pi}$ are algebraically independent, meaning that $p^{\pi}$ is transcendental. But the equation $1+(p^{\pi})^{r_2}=(p^{\pi})^{r_1}$ contradicts the transcendence of $p^{\pi}$.

Case 2: $a=1$ (meaning that $\log a=0$) but $\log b$ and $\log c$ are linearly independent. Since $b$ and $c$ are integers greater than 1, $\log b$ and $\log c$ are nonzero real numbers, while $i\pi$ is a (nonzero) imaginary number, so $\log p$ and $i\pi$ are linearly independent. Thus Schanuel's conjecture implies that three of the numbers $x_1=\log b, e^{x_1}=b, x_2=\log c, e^{x_2}=c, x_3=i\pi, e^{x_3}=-1$ are algebraically independent. Since $b$, $c$ and $-1$ are algebraic, it must be $\log b$, $\log c$ and $i\pi$ that are algebraically independent. Thus $\pi\log b$ and $\pi\log b$ is linearly independent with $\log p$ and $i\pi$, so Schanuel's conjecture implies that five of the numbers $x_1=\log b, e^{x_1}=b, x_2=\log c, e^{x_2}=c, x_3=i\pi, e^{x_3}=-1, x_4=\pi\log b, e^{x_4}=b^{\pi}, x_5=\pi\log c, e^{x_5}=c^{\pi}$ are algebraically independent. But the equation $1+b^{\pi}=c^{\pi}$ contradicts the algebraic independence of $b^{\pi}$ and $c^{\pi}$.

Case 3: $\log a$, $\log b$ and $\log c$ are nonzero but rational multiples of each other. This means that $r_1\log a = r_2\log b = r_3\log c$ and $a^{r_1}=b^{r_2}=c^{r_3}$ for integers $r_1$, $r_2$ and $r_3$. Write $a=p^{r_2r_3}$ (so that $\log a = r_2r_3\log p$), $b=p^{r_1r_3}$ (so that $\log b = r_1r_3\log p$) and $c=p^{r_1r_2}$ (so that $\log c = r_1r_2\log p$). Like before, Schanuel's conjecture implies that the three numbers $x_1=\log p, x_2=i\pi, e^{x_3}=p^{\pi}$ are algebraically independent. But the equation $(p^{\pi})^{r_2r_3}+(p^{\pi})^{r_1r_3}=(p^{\pi})^{r_1r_2}$ contradicts the transcendence of $p^{\pi}$.

Case 4: $\log a$, $\log b$ and $\log c$ are nonzero and two of them are linearly independent but not all three of them are. This means that $r_1\log a + r_2\log b = r_3\log c$ and $a^{r_1}b^{r_2}=c^{r_3}$ for integers $r_1$, $r_2$ and $r_3$. Write $a=p^{r_3}$ (so that $\log a = r_3\log p$), $b=q^{r_3}$ (so that $\log b = r_3\log q$) and $c=p^{r_1}q^{r_2}$ (so that $\log c = r_1\log p+r_2\log q$). Like before, Schanuel's conjecture implies that the five numbers $x_1=\log p, x_2=\log q, x_3=i\pi, e^{x_4}=p^{\pi}, e^{x_5}=q^{\pi}$ are algebraically independent. But the equation $(p^{\pi})^{r_3}+(q^{\pi})^{r_3}=(p^{\pi})^{r_1}(q^{\pi})^{r_2}$ contradicts the algebraic independence of $p^{\pi}$ and $q^{\pi}$.

Case 5: $\log a$, $\log b$ and $\log c$ are nonzero and linearly independent. Like before, Schanuel's conjecture implies that the seven numbers $x_1=\log a, x_2=\log b, x_3=\log c, x_4=i\pi, e^{x_5}=a^{\pi}, e^{x_6}=b^{\pi}, e^{x_7}=c^{\pi}$ are algebraically independent. But the equation $a^{\pi}+b^{\pi}=c^{\pi}$ contradicts the algebraic independence of $a^{\pi}$, $b^{\pi}$ and $c^{\pi}$.